# File not found Custom Action SharePoint 2007

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've googled a lot, but I just can't get a clue of what's happening here:

I developed a Custom Action in the ECB for Document libraries in MOSS 2007, it changes the document name with the company standard.

It is a custom action feature that redirects to a custom developed page,
The only thing the page does, is to change the name of the document and redirect the user back to the site´s main page

It works quite good in all sites but one, and I cannot find why.

It keeps throwing the following "File not found" error:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/521/errorbx.png/]

The error comes out before it loads the page so I'm not able to debug it.

I will appreciate any idea of figuring out what's happening

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneral/thread/75048569-2328-4b42-b86e-c762f235707d ?

Comment: Could you also paste code where you get SPWeb instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error is occuring when part of your code is trying to open an SPweb object based on a url.

Given it happens for just the one site, I would start by trying to figure why this site is different. Perhaps it has been moved or renamed. 
Also try a few calls SPWeb.Open with likely Urls to see if anything stands out.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using SPWeb.Open in a test application, that way I could debug and see what was happening.